# How to loop over fields from query?

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to create nodes from information extracted from a SQL query by using the following:

```
db_set_active('sage');
$query = db_query('SELECT CLIENT_ID, MASTER_CLIENT_ID, PARTICIPANT_ID FROM sage.CLIENT');
$result = $query->execute();
foreach($result as $record) {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = (string)$record->participant_id;
  $node->client_id = (string)$record->client_id;
  $node->master_client_id = (string)$record->master_client_id;
}
```

However, from my `echo` statements, I can see that my code never even enters the loop.

I had thought that `execute()` returns me an object of the query to loop over, but I guess I was wrong.

Could someone please tell me how I can loop over the results of my query and get the fields?

Comment: Are you sure your SQL should return something?

Comment: @LesterPeabody, Ya it is, I just tried it again and it returns me what I expect.

Comment: Excellent.  Good luck with all your future endeavors.

Comment: @LesterPeabody, Do you see an error with my query or code?

Comment: Not necessarily a syntax error.  It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

should do the trick.

There's a lot more info and several more examples in http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/dbtng_example!dbtng_example.module/7

Answer (score 1):

Also: `db_query()` does the execute for you. You only need `$result = db_query('SELECT thingie FROM whatever')'` and then loop through the results.

But you really want `db_select()`.

```
$columns = array('CLIENT_ID', 'MASTER_CLIENT_ID', 'PARTICIPANT_ID')
$query = db_select('client', 'c');
$query->fields('c', $columns);
$results = $query->execute();
while($record = $results->fetchAssoc()) {
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'your_node_type';
  node_object_prepare($node);
  foreach($columns as $column) {
    $node->$column = $record[$column];
  }
  node_save($node);
}
```

Each $record is an associative array, keyed by the column name, thanks to fetchAssoc(). So you'll have $record['CLIENT_ID'], etc. You'd then add them to the $node object however you want/need to.

Some helpful hints here: http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7

Comment: Paul, I looked further into the problem. If I were to loop only with the following: `$query = db_query('SELECT CLIENT_ID, MASTER_CLIENT_ID, PARTICIPANT_ID FROM sage.CLIENT');` and `foreach($query as $record)` I am unable to print out anything if I try to `echo $record->$client_id`. However, the number of times I loop is equal to the number of results returned by the query. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Updated the answer. Each $record is an associative array, keyed by the column name, thanks to fetchAssoc(). So you'll have $record['CLIENT_ID'], etc. You'd then add them to the $node object however you want/need to.